# Why does Ubuntu terminal display tab characters printed in a loop differently?

Tags: c, io, ubuntu-20.04

I am doing `printf("\t%d", i)` in a for-loop to print column labels for a table.

Before the loop, I do `printf("some string ===>")`.

An issue I notice is that for example, if I do `printf("some string===>"` (one character less), the first tab from the loop doesn't display correctly in my Ubuntu 20.04 terminal.

Why is this?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
     printf("some string ===>");
     for (int j = 1; j <= 9; ++j) printf("\t%d", j);
     printf("\n");
     
     printf("some string===>");
     for (int j = 1; j <= 9; ++j) printf("\t%d", j);
     printf("\n");
}
```

Output in my Ubuntu 20.04 terminal
[image: Output in my Ubuntu 20.04 terminal]

Comment: Because the 'title' output is longer, and pushes the output to the next 'tabstop'? Please note that `TAB` formatting has **limited utility**. Better to use field width formatting, for example `printf("%8d", val)` or `printf("%*d", width, val)`

Comment: "the first tab from the loop doesn't display correctly" --> incorrect conclusion.  The output is as directed.

Comment: ... which allows the first 'title' field to be formatted to a greater width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TAB character means, "move to the next tab stop", where tab stops are usually every 8 characters.

Consider this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < i; j++) putchar('*');
        printf("\tx\n");
    }
}
```

On my computer (with 8-character tabstops), it prints:

```
        x
*       x
**      x
***     x
****    x
*****   x
******  x
******* x
********        x
*********       x
**********      x
***********     x
************    x
*************   x
**************  x
*************** x
```

Your string `"some string ===>"` is 16 characters long, so after you print it, you're at a multiple of 8, so printing a TAB moves you 8 more spaces to the next multiple of 8 (24).

Your string `"some string===>"` is 15 characters long, so after you print it, you're one shy of a multiple of 8, so printing a TAB moves you 1 more space, to 16.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using tabs to align columns, use the width field.
`%-20s` will left justify the text in a 20 character wide field.
`%5d` will right justify the text in a 5 character wide field.
If the length of the text is greater than the specified width, the field will be expanded to accommodate the text.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
     printf( "%-20s", "some string ===>");
     for (int j = 1; j <= 9; ++j) printf("%5d", j);
     printf("\n");

     printf( "%-20s", "some string===>");
     for (int j = 1; j <= 9; ++j) printf("%5d", j);
     printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Nice (except s/b "left justify the text in a _minimum_ 20 character wide field.")